# is there a good registrar for .com.br and .it?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I am searching a good registrar (not godaddy) for

```
.com.br 
.it
.fr
.de
.ch
.es
```

Is there someone who can take it all?
I would go with Enom but it hasn't `.fr .com.br .ch .es`

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EuroDNS](http://www.eurodns.com/) claim to offer registration for all of the domain extensions you list (and more).

Comment: thanks! do you if they are good? their dns server are fast? Years ago I used this then switched to gandi.net don't remeber why (maybe for the price a bit too high but i am not sure) Lol yes the price was... .com.br at 118€/year... that's so high :(

Comment: @yes123 I haven't used the service, I'm afraid, but had it bookmarked in case I wanted some country-specific domain extensions. 118€/year does seem a little expensive, but perhaps that's what you pay for the convenience of having all of your domains under one registrar?

Comment: i guess so.. do you know any resources to know how good is their service?

Comment: @yes123 Try searching for [EuroDNS reviews](http://www.google.com/search?q=eurodns+reviews) (and "EuroDNS vouchers").

Answer (score 1):

http://www.europeregistry.com is another one!

Comment: nice +1. altho .com.br there costs 159€ XD

Comment: I know they are not exactly cheap.